# How to link to cell in another worksheet based on cell value

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a hyperlink to a cell on a sheet in a different worksheet based on the value of a cell in the current sheet.  I found this, which seems like what I'm looking for, however I only get 'Formula Parse Error'.

```
=hyperlink(concatenate("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k0jlt1A6Uen3DkllTbn430dxy-9HMCWMk2fYYGtsKB0/edit#gid=14&range=","B",match(A5,'192.154'!B:B,0)),'LINK')
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: 'LINK' in double quotes => `"LINK"`

Comment: Thanks! that removes the error, but then I just get the text 'Link' in the field and don't actually get a hyperlink. Any ideas?

Comment: It works fine for me. Are you sure that your match function is returning a number?